# How to call pandas dataframe apply function to return two variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to call pandas dataframe `apply()` function to return two variables

For examples:

```
print(word_list)
['abc', 'lmn', ]

def is_related_content(x):
    for y in word_list:
        if y in x:
            return x, y
    return '', ''

print(df.head())
    str1        
    abcdef      
    hijklmn     
    asddada    
    
# call apply() function like this
df['string'], df['substring'] = df['str1'].apply(lambda x: is_related_content(x))

# it should be like this
print(df.head())
    str1        string      substring
    abcdef      abcdef      abc
    hijklmn     hijklmn     lmn
    asddada     None        None
```

But I got error messages as follows:

> news_df['merge_' + col], news_df[col] = news_df['content'].fillna("").apply(lambda x: is_related_content(x)) 
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `is_related_content` is returning tuple for each values in the column the function is applied, so trying to assign the value like that won't work, since each rows will have tuple of values. One solution would be to apply `pd.Series` to each individual tuples, and assign them back to the list of the columns for the dataframe; *the idea is to split the tuples to multiple columns* (similar to `explode` which splits the values to multiple rows):

```py
>>> df[['string', 'substring']] = df['str1'].apply(is_related_content).apply(pd.Series)
>>> df
      str1   string substring
0   abcdef   abcdef       abc
1  hijklmn  hijklmn       lmn
2  asddada
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a tuple of Series for the **unpacking** syntax to work. But `apply` method is returning a Series of tuples. You can use `.str` accessor after `apply` in order to unpack the result as a tuple:

Updates:

```
s = df['str1'].apply(lambda x: is_related_content(x))
df['string'], df['substring'] = s.str[0], s.str[1]
df
#      str1   string substring
#0   abcdef   abcdef       abc
#1  hijklmn  hijklmn       lmn
#2  asddada
```

---

```
df['string'], df['substring'] = df['str1'].apply(lambda x: is_related_content(x)).str

df
#      str1   string substring
#0   abcdef   abcdef       abc
#1  hijklmn  hijklmn       lmn
#2  asddada
```

Comment: But it gave a warning like this, `FutureWarning: Columnar iteration over characters will be deprecated in future releases.
  df['string'], df['substring'] = df['str1'].apply(lambda x: is_related_content(x)).str
`. I have searched `Columnar iteration` before, but I did not find something related to it. If not mind, could you help me explain it.