# How to match multiple keywords with string, split multiple List[Tuples] into tuples, and append these tuples into the corresponding pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to match multiple keywords with string, split multiple List[Tuples] into tuples, and append these tuples into the corresponding dataframe.

```
print(word_list)
['abc', 'lmn', ]

def is_related_content(x):
        res_list = []
        for y in word_list:
            if y in x:
                tmp_res = (x, y)
                res_list.append(tmp_res)
    return '', ''

print(df.head())
    str1        
    abcdeflmn      
    hijklmnabc 
    abcd    
    asddada    
    
    
# call apply() function like this
# and call other functions to split List[Tuple] into Tuples then append it into `df`
# AND IT IS A IMPLEMENTATION PROBLEM HERE
df[['string', 'substring']] = df['str1'].apply(lambda x: is_related_content(x))...

# it should be like this
print(df.head())
    str1        string      substring
    abcdeflmn   abcdeflmn   abc
    abcdeflmn   abcdeflmn   lmn
    hijklmnabc  hijklmnabc  abc
    hijklmnabc  hijklmnabc  lmn
    abcd        abcd        abc
    asddada     None        None
```

This is an updated question of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333862/how-to-call-pandas-dataframe-apply-function-to-return-two-variables), which means I have a more complex requirement to fix.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def is_related_content(x):
    rv = []
    for w in word_list:
        if w in x:
            rv.append({"str1": x, "string": x, "substring": w})
    return rv or [{"str1": x}]


x = df["str1"].apply(is_related_content).explode().apply(pd.Series)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
         str1      string substring
0   abcdeflmn   abcdeflmn       abc
0   abcdeflmn   abcdeflmn       lmn
1  hijklmnabc  hijklmnabc       abc
1  hijklmnabc  hijklmnabc       lmn
2        abcd        abcd       abc
3     asddada         NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Sry to reply to you so late. When I try to use this code snippet that there is a problem that `x` in your code whose row number is larger than the original dataframe. So I guess the best way to let these two new columns into this dataframe is to use `merge()`. Is this right or not?